# Import json to MongoDB that is not supported

Tags: json, mongodb, import

I have a json file that im trying to import into MongoDB.
The compass says it is invalid json so I used the mongoimport command,
it did imporot it but everything is in 1 row.

How can I make it so the following json format is imported as while using the id as the main id instead of the auto generated ObjectId.

```
{
    "id": {
        "value1": "value"
    },
    "id": {
        "value1": "value",
        "value2": "value"
    }
}
```

("id" is a string with the value of the actual id so the json doesnt actually have "id" there)

I guess one way to solve this is to fully reformat my json file to the correct format but I have a lot of records in the json and would like to keep it this way.

edit:
I have reformatted my jsons and everything works.

Comment: you probably have a json array. If so, [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption-mongoimport-jsonarray) has an option to specify the input as json array as either `--jsonArray` or `/jsonArray`. You can check more options using the --help flag.

Comment: I tried importing it as jsonArray but I get errors if I do that saying that the format isnt correct.

Comment: Hey i'm still curious on how to-do this, any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: There are a couple of things that point out:

1. You have the `id` key repeated twice in one object which should be avoided. As the last value of the key will be taken in context and the previous one will be discarded.
2. The so-called `ObjectId` field in mongo is represented by `_id` and not `id`. So, if you want your `id` values to be treated as `_id` rename the field.
if possible can you try you json in [jsonlint](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) and validate its a proper json.

Comment: In my json where I have "id" it is a random generated id I used. "id" was example maybe I should have written that down.